# PhD Thesis with multiple preambles (Thesis by Journal Publication)

Tags: thesis

I am writing my PhD thesis in latex using the published articles/journals in IEEE Transactions on Communication. I have three articles, each of which is to form a chapter in the thesis. However, the main latex document has a different preamble from that of IEEE transactions.

The main document looks like this,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{}

\begin{document}

\input{chapter-one.tex}

\input{chapter-two.tex} % ARTICLE NUMBER ONE (IEEE Preamble)

\input{chapter-three.tex} % ARTICLE NUMBER TWO (IEEE Preamble)

\input{chapter-four.tex} % ARTICLE NUMBER THREE (IEEE Preamble)

\input{Chapter-five.tex} % CONCLUSION

\end{document}


The IEEE Preamble  in the published articles look like this,

\documentclass[a4paper,doublecolumn]{IEEEtrans}

\begin{document}

\title{}

\author{}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}

\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
Hello World!

\bibliographystyle{./IEEEtrans}

\bibliography{./IEEEabrv, ./References_File}
\end{document}
```

I have been going through the faqs and I have not really had anything that may be of help to me. I will appreciate some pointers on how to go about this.

Regards

Comment: why not simply attach the original pdf's of the publications using `pdfpages` ?

Comment: The closest to what you are trying to do is what make the [combine](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) class,  but  I second the Elad suggestion, or simply make a main preable compatible with the subdocuments and  use `the docmute` or `standalone` (see [here](https://www.ctan.org/topic/subdocs) for some more).

Comment: You have to modify your articles a bit. What was the article title becomes the chapter title. What was the article author now is the report author (you). Alle packages you needed before, you will still need.